# count rows starting from given occurrence mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

```
+----+-----+-------------+
| id | num | timestamp   |
+------------------------+
| 1  | 0   | 1565780410  |
| 2  | 1   | 1565780710  |
| 3  | 2   | 1565780510  |
| 4  | 0   | 1565780310  |
| 5  | 1   | 1565780810  |
+------------------------+
```

I would like to retrieve number of rows starting from last column 'num' with value 0 to now order by timestamp. In this case the result will be 2 (from row 4 to row 5).
So output will be:

```
+-----+
| num |
+-----+
| 2   |
+-----+
```

There is a way to do that? 
Thank you very much and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: please share output table.

Comment: Show `timestamp` example data instead of `mytimestamp` . Currently it looks like nothing depends on `timestamp` column.

Comment: you wanted say `order by id` instead of `order by timestamp`, don't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this. All you need is to find the `Max` id of column having `0` value. Then rest of the rows are your result.

For count

```
select count(1) as count from table where id >= (select Max(id) from table where num = 0 )
```

For rows

```
select * from table where id >= (select Max(id) from table where num = 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is just to consider max value for id with num equals 0, and no subquery needed :

```
select max(id) - max( case when num = 0 then id end ) + 1 as num
  from tab t

num
---
2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e8442aebd5f9690590572f8869c2f470)</kbd>